# Get Index of Array Containing Value from Multi-dimensional Array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, javascript-objects

Suppose I have a multi dimensional array in JavaScript:

```js
var arr = [
    ['cat','23','5123'],
    ['dog','53','522'],
    ['bird','335','512'],
    ['horse','853','152'], 
    ['monkey','13','5452']
];
```

And I want to get the index of the array in `arr` that contains `horse` in the first index (output should be 3).

I can do this in the following way:

```
var index_i_need;

for(var i in arr){

    if(arr[i][0]==='horse') {

        index_i_need = i;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(index_i_need);  // 3
console.log(arr[index_i_need]); // ['horse','853','152']
```

But this isnt scaleable.

Id like to have some more direct method like `indexOf()`, for instance.

I know `findIndex()` takes a callback function but I havent been able to apply it correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `arr.findIndex(sa => sa[0] === "horse");`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dynamic find function, `findByAnimal`, to use in findIndex

```
function findByAnimal(animal) {
  return function(innerArr){
    return innerArr[0] === animal
  }
}

arr.findIndex( findByAnimal('horse') )
```

The way findIndex works is each item in arr is passed into the callback, the first "truthy" return value from callback will yield the index, or -1 if no items return truthy.

Comment: Thanks @James, I quickly realized the same and updated the answer

Comment: @yevg if you found this useful, feel free to mark as answered or provide feedback. thanks